# How to store credentials with Xamarin.Auth in a list and keep adding value onto it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am storing some cardcredentials and i look to display the last 4 digits in a list but i am not sure how i can keep adding data.

With my current code it doesnt keep adding onto the list, instead it replaces the old one.

```
async void AddCard (object s, Eventargs e) 
{
    Account account = new Account();
    account.Username = "Credentials";
    account.Properties.Add("LastFour", LastFourString);
    account.Properties.Add("CardBrand", BrandString);
    account.Properties.Add("CardToken", TokenString);
    AccountStore.Create().Save(account, "Credentials");
    AddNewCard();
}

public class Info
{
    public string LastFour { get; set; }
    public string CardBrand { get; set; }
    public string CardToken { get; set; }
} 

async void AddNewCard()
{

    var Account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService("Credentials");
        var InfoList = new List<Info>();

        foreach (var Data in Account)
        {
            InfoList.Add(new Info()
            {
                LastFour = "**********" + Data.Properties["LastFour"],
                CardBrand = Data.Properties["CardBrand"]
                CardToken = Data.Properties["CardToken"]

            });
        }
        CardListView.ItemsSource = InfoList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid async void if possible. For example, it seems that AddCard method is an event handler for a button, so its signature is fixed, but you can use async Task for add new card method.

For your requirement, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage easily.

Comment: Xamarin.Auth works for forms so i rather stick with this system if possible. I changed the func too async Task now instead

Comment: Xamarin essentials is for both forms & droid/ios apps

Comment: Alright. Xamarin Auth should work just as good though i suppose? When i googled that was what recommended when to store sensitive data